# In MVC, what is the standard responsibility of View?

Tags: class, oop, model-view-controller

In MVC, what is the standard responsibility of View? Researching the books, examples and diagrams on the internet, I came across entirely different methodologies of interaction between model, view and controller classes.

Ie. in these cases, the view class, cannot access model directly.

[image: View Cannot Access Model]

[image: View Cannot Access Model 2]

However, in this example, the view should represent the data from the model and have interaction with the model class. And no interaction with the controller.

[image: Model Updates View]

In other examples, view class has interaction with both model and controller classes:

[image: View interacts with both model and controller 1]

[image]

So I am a bit puzzled about which one is the standard way or best practice.

Comment: Where did you get these pictures what are your sources? I'd suggest to follow what big companies did so Microsoft ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx ) is a good example

Comment: The important thing is, that a view must not manipulate data from the model. It may read, either directly from the model or indirectly via a controller call. But to change the model, it has to request the cotroller to do that.

Comment: @UweAllner you should post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2):

I think, last two diagrams are completely against to MVC logic. Presentation layer should be isolated from business logic. If you need to take any information from business logic on view layer, you must pass them to presentation layer with response context in controller. Also if you need to manipulate any information on model side with your request, you must figure out this problem in your controller side :)

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is, that a view must not manipulate data from the model. It may read, either directly from the model or indirectly via a controller call. But to change the model, it has to request the controller to do that.